# appending values to numpy array

Tags: numpy

I have two different arrays b0 and b1 where:
b0=[1,2]
b1=[3,4]

I want list[1st element of b0, 1st element of b1] to appended into new array B
and similarly:
list[2nd element of b0, 2nd element of b1] to appended into new array B
and so on......

that is my new array should be something like:
array([1,3],[2,4])

Below is my code:

```
b0=np.array([1,2])
b1=np.array([3,4])

for val in range(len(b1)):
    L=[b0[val],b1[val]]
    B=np.append(L,axis=0)
print(B)
```

I am getting missing on positional argument values error. Kindly help me to fix it.

Comment: Please take a look at the help or documentation. The signature is `numpy.append(arr, values, axis=None)`, so you need an array `arr`, the values `values` you want to append to `arr` and optionally the `axis`.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist to use numpy array, this is what I would do.

```
new = []
for x, y in zip(b0, b1):
    new.append([x, y])

new = np.array(new)
```

Or list comprehension

```
new = np.array([[x,y] for x, y in zip(b0, b1)])
```

Result:

```
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using np.append here isn't the most convenient way in my opinion. You can always cast python list into np.array and it's much easier to just use zip in this case.

```
b0=np.array([1,2])
b1=np.array([3,4])
B=np.array(list(zip(b0,b1)))
```

output:

```
>>> B
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [51]: b0=np.array([1,2]) 
    ...: b1=np.array([3,4])
```

Order's wrong:

```
In [56]: np.vstack((b0,b1))                                                  
Out[56]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

but you can transpose it:

```
In [57]: np.vstack((b0,b1)).T                                                
Out[57]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

`stack` is a more general purpose concatenator

```
In [58]: np.stack((b0,b1), axis=1)                                           
Out[58]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

or with:

```
In [59]: np.column_stack((b0,b1))                                            
Out[59]: 
array([[1, 3],
       [2, 4]])
```

More details on combining arrays in my other recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56159553/901925

All these, including `np.append` use `np.concatenate`, just tweaking the dimensions in different ways first.  `np.append` is often misused.  It isn't a list append clone.  None should be used repeatedly in a loop. They make a new array each time, which isn't very efficient.